# What is happening in visual studio? Form code duplicating with each click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

A colleague has some odd behaviour I've never seen before within VS Community 2015;

A userform `Form1` was created in a vb project some time ago. Some stuff has happened since now and then, we don't know what...

**Problem:** Each time he clicks on the `Form1.vb` tab in the main window, it duplicates the tab and copies all the code, with the tab getting a new suffix with this nomenclature `Form1.vb:2`

...another click... `Form1.vb:3`
...and on and on.... `Form1.vb:4` etc.

I've looked for various things - duplicating code in visual studio, cloning code, shortcuts, tabs, colons... but finding code solutions rather than VS IDE answers.

**Any idea what this is, what it's for and how to toggle it on/off?**

Comment: Sounds more like a bug than a feature.  Does it only happen with this one form?

Comment: Yup, the other form is fine - very odd, feels like a hidden feature we've accidentally turned on with the whole `:x` but could easily be a bug too - never seen that before.

Comment: In case of "strange problems" the standard question is "have you tried turning it off and on again?". Did you (just asking to be sure)?

Comment: You are describing the effect of `Window - New Window` which opens a new editor window for the same code module. It's unclear why it would happen on a simple click. Do you have extensions installed?

Comment: Nope, nothing fancy at all, default settings I think. It's been restarted and is still displaying the same behaviour so we're putting it down to glitch in the project and starting from scratch :/